# BLE GATT Design - Discreet or generic characteristics

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm working on designing a custom GATT service for a device and I'm contemplating using a more generic approach for our services/characteristics versus the standard discreet services and characteristics for each data point.

In our scenario this device will not need to be used with other servers/vendors so we will only be the company needing to interface with the device.  So it seems like abstracting out each discreet data point has less value.

The generic approach would entail a single service with three characteristics:

- genericCustomService

  - readNotifyCharacteristic - data needing read and/or notify operations

    - input

      - fieldIdentifier
    - output

      - fieldIdentifier
      - fieldDataLength
      - fieldData
  - writeCharacteristic - data needing write operations

    - input

      - fieldIdentifier
      - fieldDataLength
      - fieldData
    - output

      - success or fail

The discreet approach (best practice from what I can tell) would mean multiple services with characteristics grouped logically:

- customService1

  - characteristic1.1
  - characteristic1.2
  - characteristic1.3
- customService2

  - characteristic2.1
  - characteristic2.2
  - characteristic2.3
  - characteristic2.4
- customService3

  - etc...

Implementation seems like it would be easier for the generic approach both on the device BLE server and client.

Thoughts/feedback from real experiences?

Comment: You can use two characteristics. One for sending data on and one for receiving (notifications). Then encode whatever you need in the raw bytes that you transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good thing with using as few services/characteristics as possible is that Service Discovery time will be much shorter than if you have a large GATT db. The Service Discovery protocol is a very inefficient one, resulting in a huge amount of round-trips. This will directly affect the time it takes to establish a connection. If your devices are bonded though, Service Discovery can fortunately be skipped.

If you only have a simple device, like a heart rate monitor, cycling speed sensor or similar where the GATT philosophy makes sense and it doesn't result in that many characteristics, you are usually fine following this approach.

If you however plan to make use of more advanced communication including tons of features, which might change in firmware upgrades, it might be easier to just have TX/RX characteristics and encode/decode the data yourself with some custom protocol (such as the first byte represents opcode and the rest of the data are parameters). Otherwise if you use the GATT structure and add a characteristic or service and assuming you are using bonding so that the GATT db will be cached in the client, you will most likely need to properly use and implement the Service Changed Indication feature, keep track of which clients you have sent this indication to, and hope that Android or whatever Bluetooth stack runs on the client is bug-free and correctly refreshes the GATT cache and notifies your app when the GATT db was updated (Android does not really do this before Android 12).

Error handling can also be easier with only TX/RX characteristics. What happens in your app if one or a few expected characteristics are missing, but others are present? (I noticed this bug once in a cheap Lenovo tablet) Your `onServicesDiscovered` method must probably be more advanced to verify that all characteristics are correct before continuing if you have many characteristics/services.

Also note that, you could use L2CAP CoC as well if you just want to send/receive data, which is implemented in both Android >= 10 and iOS.

Comment: Is it commonly necessary to reinvent a custom multiplexing protocol with the TX/RX characteristics approach (mentioned by Nipo's answer below).

Comment: If you only want to make a simple thermometer or whatever then I assume most people would use the full GATT approach. People seeing BLE as a generic transport method and want to be able to use the same high level protocol on top of any lower level protocol (BLE, WebSocket, UART, etc.) would just use TX/RX characteristics. People that are not satisfied with BLE security (for example the lack of being able to use a static few-digit printed passkey to "pair") and want to implement their own PAKE+AEAD like "Matter" (C.H.I.P.) on top of BLE would most likely use simple TX/RX characteristics.

Comment: Another awkward thing with GATT is that there is no request-response with data transactions defined, i.e. when you want to send some bytes in a request and receive some bytes in response. You must either first send a write and then wait for a notification, or first send a write request and then send a read request to read the response.

Answer (score 1):

What you are thinking about is basically another Att protocol on top of Att/GATT, but unless you think about all corner cases and extensibility, you'll get less features for more development cost.

Pros:

- no need to understand philosophy of BLE GATT,
- no need to embrace Att/GATT protocols, this will just be a transparent transport protocol.

Cons:

- need to reinvent a custom muxing protocol,
- need to allocate IDs in the custom protocol, maintain allocation,
- will reduce MTU (and it is not so big in BLE already), as you will need a few bytes for the muxing protocol,
- loss of all generic infrastructure (protocol analysers, client code, generic client APIs (think iOS/Android code), generic client apps (many generic client apps for PC, phone)),
- loss of self-descriptiveness of GATT,
- versioning more tedious to achieve (think about future firmware versions that expose more data, or expose data in another form, think about future products with slightly different featureset).

Overall, I see no good reason to do this.

GATT is a method for making Att self-descriptive. You may create custom services, with generic or custom characteristics, each of them is supposed to expose one value. This has some nice features. For each characteristic, you have:

- a type identifier (actually an UUID, either standard or custom),
- standard access methods (read, write, notify, indicate),
- standard access rights (e.g. only access after pairing),
- optional descriptors (you may specify actual encoding of data in a standard manner, add names).

You may create one or many custom services with all your "datapoints" as distinct characteristics in it. Having only one custom service with all your custom characteristics in it is perfectly fine. This is mostly application-dependent.

You'll probably have generic standard services belong-side, like battery service, device information service or software update.

See [Bluetooth GATT serivce uuid overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017350/bluetooth-gatt-serivce-uuid-overview/60100785#60100785) for ID allocation scheme.

Comment: Have you seen Service Discovery time slow down with 19 characteristics across 2-3 custom services as suggested by Emil in his answer above?

Comment: Discovery time is linear to number of services and characteristics and is meant to be cached. Either you are latency sensitive, you stay connected and use slave latency, or you are not and can afford a few 100s of ms reconnection time. Overall, this is a non-problem to me.