# android Bluetooth develop about uuid

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently learning bluetooth and know android connect bluetooth device, it needs *uuid* for read / write or more.
But I don't know what does *uuid* mean such as "0000fff4-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", but I found it can use in get blood pressure value. But is it the standard of Bluetooth? And, it has website to search the *uuid* and the usage and characteristic?

I cannot find it in the Bluetooth website.

I hope to know what is *uuid* in the Bluetooth device, and is it standard or not? Or does it need according to the device factory provide?

Thanks.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017350/bluetooth-gatt-service-uuid-overview/60100785#60100785 to get an overview of UUIDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website of the Bluetooth SIG has a specification of all [assigned numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) available. You can find all predefined UUIDs in their [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf) (direct link). The 16-bit UUID for the Blood Pressure Service would be 0x1810, so no, your UUID is not a standard address.

You can find more information about the Blood Pressure Service and how to use it and other services in the [specification list](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/).