# WebBluetooth GATT, filter by custom service UUID

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm unable to filter by Service UUID using the `bluetooth.requestDevice` Web Bluetooth Gatt API

My device named MyDevice1 with the service UUID: "607cdd4f-32aa-47da-8209-18f12012e3a4" which has been randomly generated from here: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

The following works fine and I can find my device:

```
    return navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
          
        filters: [{
            namePrefix: "MyDevice"
        }]
}).then......
```

But this does not work:

```
    return navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
          
        filters: [{
            namePrefix: "MyDevice",
            services: ["607cdd4f-32aa-47da-8209-18f12012e3a4"] // matches device only service UUID

        }]
}).then......
```

I've checked the device ID and it's definitely correct.

I it a the case that you can only use predefined UUID or can custom ones be generated for filtering? I've been using Chrome for testing.

Related Information: [Bluetooth GATT service uuid overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017350/bluetooth-gatt-service-uuid-overview)

Comment: How did you check the UUID? Have you tried using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? You can use it to view the service UUID as well as use a filter to find only your device

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I set the UUID myself in the ESP32 module, I'll check as you have suggested if it's using a different one, but not sure why it would. 

I was thinking maybe the issue is I'm testing BLE from localhost and plan to check it from a domain soon, maybe that is the issue

Comment: Just for completenes, when you find your device without setting a service filter, can you read the service UUID? Maybe it is expected in a different format